# Modifying variable values inside a For loop in Windows shell script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to perform operations on first 4 files in a folder.  So, the counter variable has to increment during each operation of the For loop.  The following piece of code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET TESTDIR1=D:\Local Data\Shell Script\test folder 1

SET _transfer=XXXX

FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir "%TESTDIR1%\*" /b/a-d/o-d') DO (
    SET _transfer=%_transfer:~1%
    ECHO %_transfer%
)
```

prints "XXXX" for every iteration of the loop.  Why might that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
FOR /f "TOKENS=1*delims=[]" %%i IN ('dir "%TESTDIR1%\*" /b/a-d/o-d^|find /n /v ""') DO (
 if %%1 LEQ 4 echo %%j
)
```

Your approach doesn't work because batch replaces any `%var%` within a block (a parenthesised sequence of commands) with the value of `var` before the block is executed. See any number of SO questions related to `delayed expansion` for more info.